# Accidentally changed sys files ownership - Centos 7

Tags: linux, permissions, centos, putty, ownership

I accidentally changed the ownership of several files including system files in our `Centos 7` server due to a syntax error. I was trying to change it for a particular folder, but missed the `.` and ended up executing `\`. Now I can't even remote login to the machine through `Putty/Cygwin`. It says `Connection disconnected`. Is the server hosed or is there a way to restore the default permissions to atleast `system files` so I can login and go from there?

So far from my research  I think I'm out of luck.  Any tips?

Also, is there a way to copy files from the hard disk if it can't be restored like connecting it as slave in Windows machine?

Comment: Starting from the end, Windows does not support any of the file systems typically used in Unux/Linux. And the attempts to restore the default file permissions have to be done locally.

Comment: I can login to the machine, seems like its not fully corrupted. But cant remote login using Putty/Cygwin. Tried reassigning ssh/sysconfig folders and sub folders groups back to root but still no luck. What else could be missing that prohibits the remote connection?

Comment: I think I fixed it. Ended up reinstalling the openssh as the host key files were having issues. Now it connects through putty/cygwin.

Answer (score 1):

Consider this link
http://www.adminlinux.org/2009/07/how-to-restore-default-system.html
ne liner that does the job, it takes time but It works !!!!!

1. To reset uids and gids on files and directories:
   `for u in $(rpm -qa); do rpm --setugids $u; done`
2. To permissions on files and directories: `for p in $(rpm -qa); do rpm --setperms $p; done`

Answer (score 0):

You can boot off a live CD, mount the filesystem to a mount point, chroot into it, and restore rpm file permissions with `rpm --setperms {packagename}`

oooor, you can reinstall :-)